# Deleting CCSprites stored in NSMutableArray not working right

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, removechild, ccsprite

Here is what I've tried.

In my init method I initialized the array:

```
deleteSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:500];
```

This is how I added them to the array:

```
CCSprite *SpriteSave;
SpriteSave = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:Batch rect:CGRectMake(0,0,6,6)];
[Batch addChild:SpriteSave];
[deleteSprites addObject:SpriteSave];
```

This is how I attempt to remove the sprites:

```
delCount = 0;
while (delCount < [deleteSprites count])
    CCSprite *delSprite = (CCSprite *) [deleteSprites objectAtIndex:delCount];
    [delSprite.parent removeChild:delSprite cleanup:YES];
    delCount++;
}
[deleteSprites removeAllObjects];
```

This causes some of the sprites to flip, but they still appear on screen and none are deleted.  I've already researched everywhere and although I made my code very similar to others that got it to work, it still won't work for me.  I've also already read through the memory management documents and I still don't see what I'm doing wrong. Also I've tried adding the sprites to the userdata of the fixtures they're supposed to be representing and when the fixture is destroyed I once again try to remove the sprite but the same thing happens.  Please Help!.

I figured out what it was.  I was making a logical error in a few of my if statements and accidentally added the sprites twice.  Sorry about that everyone.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at the start of the while loop and check the debugger to confirm that deleteSprites is filled?

Comment: If you have solved it you should really answer your own question.  You then wait a day and choose it as the correct answer.  It is much easier to read for anyone who has this question in the future.